# How to submit a script partly as array

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, slurm

I'm using Slurm on my lab's server, and I would like to submit a job that looks like this:

```
#SBATCH ...

mkdir my/file/architecture
echo "#HEADER" > my/file/architecture/output_summary.txt

for f in my/dir/*.csv; do
    python3 myscript.py $f
done
```

Is there any way to run this so that it will complete the first instructions, then run the `for` loop in parallel? Each step is independant, so they can run at the same time.

The initial steps are not very complex, so if needed I could separate it into a separate SBATCH script. `my/dir/` however contains about 7000 csv files to processes, so typing them all out manually would be a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) might be a good fit here, or `xargs`, though I prefer `parallel` in Slurm jobs.

Here's an example of an `sbatch` script running an 8-way `parallel`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#SBATCH ...
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=

srun="srun --exclusive -N1 -n1"

# -j is the number of tasks parallel runs so we set it to $SLURM_NTASKS
# Note that --ntasks=1 and --cpus-per-task=8 will have srun start one copy of the program at a time. We use "find" to generate a list of files to operate on.

find /my/dir/*.csv -type f | parallel -j $SLURM_NTASKS "$srun python3 myscript.py {}"
```

The easiest way is to run on a single node, though `parallel` can use SSH (I believe) to run on multiple computers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, I was busy with another section of my project! Could you explain what the `srun="srun --exclusive -N1 -n1"` line does? My understanding is that it sets "parameters" for srun when it will be called in the `parallel` section, but I'd like to be sure :)

Comment: correct, it just makes a sort of alias to `srun`, with some default parameters.